# Where are the Energy Spheres in level 3-1?

Tags: kirby-return-to-dreamland

I went though the entire level, and I didn't see a single one. I destroyed everything I could using the Snow Bowl copy ability, and looked in all the "secret" places that I could find, and I still saw no Energy Spheres.

Where are they hiding in this level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be three.

If you see a spiked orb guarding a bomb box. You can use your Tornado ability on it to see something open up...

Defeating the Sphere Doomer, will net you the other two. Sword or Tornado will do.

Comment: The **Spear** would work fine there too.  Also make sure you keep the **Snow Bowl** ability until you reach the next section of the map when you get it.

Comment: @JeffMercado Oh, that would've been one of the things I missed for sure! I didn't keep the Snow Bowl for the next section. :)